# Low voltage GSM modules

Tags: batteries, gsm

I am developing a battery powered application. I need GSM communication there. The problem is that in most (I think every even) devices I find the required voltage is from 3.4V to 4.2V. I would really prefer the module to work on 3.3V steadily. Are there such modules? If not, what is the technological obstacle here? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: What type of power source are you hoping to use?  GSM modules have very high pulse power draw when transmitting, which many "logic project" mains supplies and primary batteries are unable to supply.  These modules are really designed around the lithium secondary batteries found in the phone applications for which the technology is developed.

Comment: Yes, I hve found out exacly that as well. It explains the 4.2-3.3V range

Comment: The issue is not so much the *voltage* but the high *current* which will be drawn.  Even if you reworked a typical breadboard supply to deliver 4.2v, it would probably fall over when the module tries to perform the initial high power (and thus current-hungry) transmissions.

Comment: Its fine at this point- I do have a li-ion 2 cell battery for this. Thanks

Comment: It needs a single cell, *not* a 2-cell.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2 pararell cells.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a boost converter to convert your 3.3 volt source to the voltage required for the GSM module.

Comment: Not so simply - are you aware that GSM modules are notorious for requiring around 2 amps when transmitting?

Answer (score 1):

They are designed to run of a single lithium cell. Like all phones do. They sometimes provide the charging and management circuitry as well.

If you want a different battery chemistry, you will need your own power supply circuitry.